# Exception Fixing ban command discord.py

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

I recently made a ban command for my bot but its not working, can anyone help? whenever i do !ban it just gives the exception and `member.kick` is blacked out, also i user kick insted of ban because of debugging purposes
Thanks!

Code:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def ban(self, ctx, member:nextcord.Member,*, reason="No Reason Provided"):
        try:
            if reason == None:
                embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Member Banned!", description=f"{member.mention} has been banned from '{ctx.guild}'\n Reason: `No Reason Provided`", colour=BLUE_COLOUR)
                embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/942086556980764722/967720168199426069/Ban_Command.gif")
                await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
                await member.kick(reason=reason)
            else:
                author = ctx.message.author.name
                SendConfirmation = nextcord.Embed(title="Member Banned! ", description=f"Banned: {member.mention}\n Moderator: **{author}** \n Reason: **{reason}**", color=GOLD_COLOUR)
                SendDM = nextcord.Embed(title="You Have been Banned", colour=BLUE_COLOUR)
                embed.add_field(name="Server Name", value=f"{ctx.guild.name}", inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"{reason}", inline=True)
                embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                await member.send(embed=SendDM)
                await ctx.reply(embed=SendConfirmation)
        except Exception:
            ErrorEmbed = nextcord.Embed(title="Something Went Wrong", description="There was an error trying to perform this command.", colour=ERROR_COLOUR)
            ErrorEmbed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            await ctx.reply(embed=ErrorEmbed)
            return
```

Comment: Why is it "blacked out"? Can you edit the exception traceback into the question?

Comment: I don't understand the exception, but it could be because `embed` is not defined in the else block.

Comment: You are catching all exceptions, I would try to remove the try/except altogether and see what error is coming up, or at least print the Exception that is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 issues with the code:

1. Your *reason* argument was never none because it was set by default on *"No Reason Provided"* so you would never use the if statement
2. you created the variable *SendDM* and then used the embed function on a new variable that was never defined (called *embed*)

   ```
   @commands.command()
   async def ban(self,ctx, member:nextcord.Member,*, reason=None):

       if reason == None:
           embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Member Banned!", description=f"{member.mention} has been banned from '{ctx.guild}'\n Reason: `No Reason Provided`")
           embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
           embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/942086556980764722/967720168199426069/Ban_Command.gif")
           await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
           await member.ban(reason=reason)
       else:
           author = ctx.message.author.name
           SendConfirmation = nextcord.Embed(title="Member Banned! ", description=f"Banned: {member.mention}\n Moderator: **{author}** \n Reason: **{reason}**")
           SendDM = nextcord.Embed(title="You Have been Banned")
           SendDM.add_field(name="Server Name", value=f"{ctx.guild.name}", inline=True)
           SendDM.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"{reason}", inline=True)
           SendDM.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
           await member.send(embed=SendDM)
           await ctx.reply(embed=SendConfirmation)
           await member.ban(reason=reason)
   ```

This code should work, I tested it on my machine, I took away embed  colors and the try and except block but you can add them back.

One last thing, I suggest to remove the *try* and *except* block and handle errors with actual error handlers. You can find how to use them in the documentation of the nextcord library.